# Data binding custom WPF control doesn't work

Tags: wpf

I wrote a custom control for DateTimePicker, but the binding value is not passed to the property correctly.

```
<cc:DateTimePicker SelDate="{Binding RA_EFFECTIVE_DATE}"/> <!-- Doesn't work -->
<cc:DateTimePicker SelDate="1.1.2014"/> <!-- Works? Which means I can see the value inside setter SelDate correctly -->
```

Here is my DateTimePicker class:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelDateProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register(
       "SelDate",
       typeof(DateTime?),
       typeof(DateTimePicker),
       new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, OnSelectedDateChanged, CoerceSelectedDate));



    public DateTime? SelDate
    {
        get { return (DateTime?)GetValue(SelDateProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelDateProperty, value); }
    }
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Check for binding errors in output window of Visual studio if any related to `RA_EFFECTIVE_DATE`.

Comment: did you implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-Us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) for the RA_EFFECTIVE_DATE-Property?

Comment: I seem to have binding problem...